# Change SlidingMenu (buttons, state, animation)

Tags: android, button, slidingmenu, drawer

I'm using jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu.
In the Activity after some action i need to do:

1. change some buttons in SlidingMenu in this activity. How can i do it?
2. remove/disable SlidingMenu, how?
3. Additional question: Is possible use SlidingMenu as Drawer? (Animation: Main content of Activity have fixed position and SlidingMenu is sliding over front of this content)

Thanks for all helps.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code inflate a different xml based on your condition

```
private void setSlidingMenu() {

        menu_sliding = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu_sliding.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);

        menu_sliding.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
        menu_sliding.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu_sliding.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu_sliding.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);

        //
        menu_sliding.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu_sliding.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);

        slidingMenuView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.sliding_menu, null);

        setUpSlidingMenuListener();

        menu_sliding.setMenu(slidingMenuView);

    }
```

Comment: This is initialization process, but I need (1) and (2) after SlidingMenu was created.